# Android - Storing and loading a folder of images stored on the web

Tags: android, image, server

I have a folder on my computer with many images. I want to have my app be able to load all of these images into a View. I have no problem loading one image from its url (using Picasso) but I want to know how to load a folder of them (i.e the amount of images may change).

I was thinking that I could use a Google Drive public folder to store the images, but how could I get the images from within the folder (i.e if I had the folder's URL could I use Java to "open and look inside" it)? Is there a better (and free) way than Google Drive to store the images? Maybe an imgur album or some kind of free server hosting service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Firebase or Alternative use is Imgur . You store images there and  the links of images tou can store in a db (sql Lite) and just add connection of db in main.activity   [Here you can learn how](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm)

Comment: If I use the SQLite method then the user will have to update the app in order to see changes in the database right? (since it is a local db)

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) for this. Upload your Images in the [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/products/storage/) and store the link in the database. Once done, you can show all the Images in your app and also dynamically add the images.